# Python: order of evaluation arithmetic expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just read https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/eval_rules.pdf
and it says on the beginning of page 5, that the expression

```
6 + 7 + 8
```

is evaluated to:

```
13 + 8
```

and then to

```
21
```

If that is the case in python, why is

```
2**1**2
```

evaluated to `2` and not to `4`

Comment: Because that's how it works in math, too. I would not want math to behave differently in Python. 2^1^2 is 2, not 4.

Comment: As it says on page 4, "Python follows the standard mathematical order of operations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) mentions:

> The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its
>   left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right.

and:

> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the
>   operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain
>   the evaluation order for the operands): -1**2 results in -1.

Comment: Which is exactly the same as it works in math. It would be weird if it worked otherwise

Answer (score 1):

So based on python 3.x docs page (the-power-operator)

"Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from *right to left* (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): "-1**2" results in -1"

so, the expression is evaluated to 2^1 (as 1^2 = 1) which is itself 2 (or in other words, with brackets, (2^(1^2))

Hope that helps